# Split an php array

Tags: php, arrays

i am using `$_POST` for getting all `input` values and it generates an array like:

```
[seen1] => 1
[flag1] => 0
[time1] => 275
[qtsnums1] => 17
[seen2] => 0
[flag2] => 0
[time2] => 0
[qtsnums2] => 11
[seen3] => 0
[flag3] => 0
[time3] => 0
[qtsnums3] => 9
[seen4] => 0
[flag4] => 0
[time4] => 0
[qtsnums4] => 5
[seen5] => 0
[flag5] => 0
[time5] => 0
[qtsnums5] => 10
```

i want to split:

```
[seen1] => 1
[flag1] => 0
[time1] => 275
[qtsnums1] => 17
```

and insert in 1 variable, how to do this?

Comment: Rephrase your question

Comment: @rr- He wants to do the operation known as chunking.

Comment: Do you need to restructure the array with 1,2,3,.. suffixes in the keys?

Comment: @all : i want to store 1st 4 array value with key in xml tag.

Comment: @Jay Your question should be closed because you haven't shown us what you've tried. Next time share us your code that fails.

Answer (score 3):

`array_chunk` will help you splitting the array:

```
$new = array_chunk($_POST, 4, true) ; //Do not forget to use TRUE to save indices

$desired_result = $new[0] ;
var_dump($desired_result) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input array is named `$input`, you can create your new array using this:

```php
$output = array();
$wantedKeys = array('seen1', 'flag1', 'time1', 'qtsnums1');
foreach ($wantedKeys as $key)
{
    $output[$key] = $input[$key];
}
print_r($output);
```

To get list containing first four keys, regardless how they are named:

```
$wantedKeys = array_slice(array_keys($input), 0, 4);
```

You can also use aforementioned `array_chunk`. If you want to get away with one-liner, you can do this:

```
$output = current(array_chunk($input, 4, true));
```

Note that it generates warning about references in newer versions of PHP. In such case you can use this:

```
$output = array_chunk($input, 4, true)[0];
```

This, however, will generate syntax error on older PHPs.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah array_slice() will do if you need only the first 4. But following is a general one, which splits the input array to different chunks.

```
$array = array(
    'seen1' => 1,
    'flag1' => 0,
    'time1' => 3,
    'qtsnums1' => 4,
    'seen2' => 1,
    'flag2' => 0,
    'time2' => 3,
    'qtsnums2' => 4,
    'seen3' => 1,
    'flag3' => 0,
    'time3' => 3,
    'qtsnums3' => 4,
);

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    preg_match('/([^0-9]+)(\d+)/', $key, $matches);
    $new_array[$matches[2]][$matches[1]] = $value;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Output will be as follows

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [seen] => 1
            [flag] => 0
            [time] => 3
            [qtsnums] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [seen] => 1
            [flag] => 0
            [time] => 3
            [qtsnums] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [seen] => 1
            [flag] => 0
            [time] => 3
            [qtsnums] => 4
        )

)
```

So giving $new_array[1] will get the 1st chunk and $new_array[2] will get 2nd chunk and so on.